# How to pass generic type to generic method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics

I want to invoke  a method accepting `T type` object. In my custom method I'm receiving `T type`. How can I pass my `T type` to the method which is already receiving a `T type`? Can it be invoked via reflection?

Below is my method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Method2<T>(string fileSrc, char sep)
{
    // Using LinqToCsv lib  
    IEnumerable<T> list;

    CsvFileDescription inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = sep,//specify the separator line  
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true //Header is in the first line  
    };
    CsvContext csvContext = new CsvContext();
    list = csvContext.Read<T>(fileSrc, inputFileDescription);

    // Data is now available via variable list.  
    return list;
}
```

In the above method  `csvContext.Read<T>(fileSrc, inputFileDescription);` is declared as

```
public IEnumerable<T> Read<T>(string fileName, CsvFileDescription fileDescription) 
    where T : class, new();
```

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: @RenéVogt as I got the answer by Martin , but still a great thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call a generic method you need to make sure that the type parameter matches the same generic constraints.

So you need to change your method declaration to

```
public IEnumerable<T> Method2<T>(string fileSrc, char sep) where T : class, new()
```

in order to invoke the the `Read<T>()` method which requires its `T` type argument to match these constraints.